# package org.apache.hadoop.fs does not exist

Tags: java, hadoop

First, I KNOW THIS HAS BEEN ASKED BEFORE, but none of the solutions work for me and I would like to know why.

I am trying to compile the standard 'WordCount.java' .jar for hadoop on my linux single-node cluster, but keep getting the `package org.apache.hadoop.* does not exist` error.

I know that I have to edit the $CLASSPATH, but everything I have found online is saying to reference `hadoop-core` and I cannot find a `hadoop-core` anywhere in my build (2.4.0). How do I find where org.apache.hadoop.* would exist on my system?

I feel this would be a good 'general' answer since I have seen many questions on this and everyone gives a specific /path/to/classpath/, but it is (apparently) different depending on version and build of hadoop.

Comment: Did you download any Apache Commons libs? what solutions have not worked for you?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you said, the CLASSPATH you need depends on version, location, and type of installation. How to install it is a separate discussion, but assuming you have a proper hadoop setup installed, it's easy (though I admit, I have no clue where it is documented).

Hadoop provides a convenient utility to get the CLASSPATH information you need.  Run this

```
bin/hadoop classpath
```

This should give you the information you need set your classpath for compiling your code.

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully this will help anyone else who is having trouble. Everything I was reading was giving specific directions on where the files were located, but this solution will help people no matter how they have it installed!

Comment: @VineetKaushik supposing you have hadoop correctly configured in your system, open a Terminal window and type `hadoop classpath` and it should output the correct directories where hadoop has its libraries.